# LibGDX I want to write a dictionary app with 100,000 english words. Can I use JSON?

Tags: android, json, dictionary, libgdx

I want to write a dictionary app with 100,000 english to english words.
My dictionary has some special function, you can "tick" the checkbox in the app
and store your understanding words in the same dictionary file e.g. JSON.

So, my question is I need a file to read and write the 100,000 words with the ability to store the status of words. Is JSON a suitable choice to read and wirte 100,000 pair of words?

If the file is too large, I think I need to split the 100,000 words into 100 files (1000 pair of words per file). Is it good idea?

Thanks!

Comment: use JSON parse it then store using Sqlite(assuming there is update).

Comment: Additionally, I'm a little intrigued on why you are using LibGDX, a popular game development framework, to write a dictionary app. Are you wanting to remain cross platform?

Comment: Tell you a bit more, it is not exactly a dictionary app. My question is just an example. Thanks.

Comment: Parsing such a big file in JSON most likely you will get Out Of Memory Exception in several cases. Happened to me before. SQLite all the way as @Zerkz answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) seems like a good choice for your scenario.